# What will be the sign of the ground state energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, schroedinger-equation, ground-state

A particle of mass $m$ moves in a 1 dimensional potential 
$V(x)$, which vanishes at infinity. The exact ground state eigenfunction is $\phi(x)=A\operatorname{sech}(\lambda x)$, where $A$ and $λ$ are constants.

Using Schrodinger equation in one dimension, I found my answer to be negative, can the ground state energy be negative? Or I am making some mistake while calculating it?

Comment: depending on the potential, the energy can be negative which may be a manifestation of a bound state.

Comment: But here type of potential is unknown, then how can we say that? And if the ground state energy is negative then that state is bounded which means what?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at, for example, quantum mechanical derivation of eigenfunctions and eigenenenergies for hydrogen atom (see http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_19.html). Keep in mind that to solve the SE you need to know the potential. If in your question the wave function is a given then it suggests that someone "knew" the potential and solved the SE and got the wave function. Bound state, again referring to hydrogen atom, means that a state in which the electron will be bound to the nucleus, that is, proton.

Comment: I tried to calculate the ground state energy. First I took the second order derivative, substituted it into the SE  and imposed the boundary condition , V(x) goes to zero as x approaches infinity then i got the solution to be negative.

Comment: All right. I do not think I understand the details of your question exactly nevertheless having the energy negative itself can not be sign of mistake.

Comment: If $\lim_{|{\bf r}|\to\infty}V({\bf r})=0$ asymptotically, then the [bound states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state) have negative energy $E_n<0$. In particular, the ground state energy $E_0$ would be non-positive. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, is it possible?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165321/find-the-energy-eigen-value-given-wave-function).

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{|{\bf r}|\to\infty}V({\bf r})=0$ asymptotically, then the [bound states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state) have negative energy $E_n<0$. In particular, the ground state energy $E_0$ would be non-positive. This is e.g. the case for [hydrogen-like atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom).